# PostgreSQL: issue with query plan

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to speed up a search query. The context is the one of Sentinel 2 products (satellite images).

Trying to fasten the spatial intersection, I have a table containing all MGRS tile geometries (squares of about 100km per 100km). Each product geometry is contained (or equal) to the one of its MGRS tile.

I have three tables:

- `mgrs_tiles`: about 60 000 tiles covering the Earth,
- `products`: about 20 millions images
- `locations`: scihub, aws or gcp links.

I created the following indices:

```sql
CREATE INDEX mgrs_geom_idx ON sentinel2.mgrs USING gist (geom);
CREATE INDEX sentinel2_query_l1c_idx
     ON sentinel2.products (mgrs_tile, id) INCLUDE (geom, sensing_time, cloud_cover)
     WHERE NOT deleted AND processing_level = 'l1c';
CREATE INDEX sentinel2_query_l2a_idx
     ON sentinel2.products (mgrs_tile, id) INCLUDE (geom, sensing_time, cloud_cover)
     WHERE NOT deleted AND processing_level = 'l2a';
```

The main goal of my query is :

- select products that fall within a BBox (that can be arbitrarily small or large),
- use several filters (temporal, cloud cover...),
- paginate the results efficiently,
- include where the product is available (aws, gcp, etc.) using the `locations` table.

I have tried several types of queries.

The products are evenly distributed between `mgrs_tile`.

**1. CTE + IN**

First idea was to use keyset pagination based on `id`, and to add a condition on `id` for next page.

```
WITH m AS (
    SELECT mgrs_tile FROM sentinel2.mgrs
    WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
)
SELECT p.id, p.deleted, p.product_id, p.processing_level, p.spacecraft, p.sensing_time, p.mgrs_tile, p.cloud_cover, p.geom, l.locations
FROM sentinel2.products p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT product_id AS _product_id, array_agg((provider, properties)) locations, array_agg(provider) providers
    FROM sentinel2.locations
    WHERE product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
) l on p.product_id = l._product_id
WHERE mgrs_tile IN (SELECT mgrs_tile FROM m)
    AND processing_level = 'l1c'
    AND _ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
    AND sensing_time > '2016-01-01'
    AND NOT deleted
    AND cloud_cover < 50
    AND 'aws' = ANY(l.providers)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000;
```

Not very efficient obviously, due to the big `IN` and the `ORDE BY id`.

**2. CTE + INNER JOIN**

After, I changed into using `mgrs_tile, id` for the pagination.
For the next page, I would use `mgrs_tile > ...` in the CTE and `id > ... AND mgrs_tile != ...` in the main query.

```
WITH m AS (
    SELECT mgrs_tile FROM sentinel2.mgrs
    WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
    AND mgrs_tile > '...'
)
SELECT p.id, p.deleted, p.product_id, p.processing_level, p.spacecraft, p.sensing_time, p.mgrs_tile, p.cloud_cover, p.geom, l.locations
FROM sentinel2.products p
INNER JOIN m on m.mgrs_tile = p.mgrs_tile
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT product_id AS _product_id, array_agg((provider, properties)) locations, array_agg(provider) providers
    FROM sentinel2.locations
    WHERE product_id = p.product_id
    GROUP BY product_id
) l on p.product_id = l._product_id
WHERE processing_level = 'l1c'
    AND _ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
    AND sensing_time > '2016-01-01'
    AND NOT deleted
    AND cloud_cover < 50
    AND (id > XXX OR mgrs_tile != '...')
    AND 'aws' = ANY(l.providers)
ORDER BY mgrs_tile, id
LIMIT 1000;
```

The query takes more than 2 minutes (I stopped after) for large bboxes, and several seconds for small bboxes.

**3. Using LATERAL**

I understood that I needed to guide the planner into not trying all mgrs tiles, but only the first ones to get the LIMIT necessary. My final take has been rewriting the query the following way:

```sql
WITH m AS (
    SELECT mgrs_tile
    FROM sentinel2.mgrs
    WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
    --AND mgrs_tile >= '...'
)
SELECT q.*
FROM m,
LATERAL (
    SELECT id, deleted, product_id, datatake_id, 
       processing_level, spacecraft, 
       sensing_time, mgrs_tile, cloud_cover, geom, l.locations
    FROM sentinel2.products p
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT product_id AS _product_id, array_agg((provider, properties)) locations, array_agg(provider) providers
        FROM sentinel2.locations
        WHERE product_id = p.product_id
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) l on p.product_id = l._product_id
    WHERE 
        mgrs_tile = m.mgrs_tile
        AND processing_level = 'l1c'
        AND _ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(0, 0, 45, 45, 4326))
        AND sensing_time > '2016-01-01'
        AND NOT deleted
        AND cloud_cover < 100
        --AND (id > ... OR mgrs_tile != '...')
        AND 'aws:sentinel-s2-l1c' = ANY(l.providers)
    ORDER BY id
) q
ORDER BY m.mgrs_tile
LIMIT 1000
```

About 500 ms for large AOIs ! Nice ! Query plan is:

```
"Limit  (cost=1001.55..14813441.54 rows=1000 width=380) (actual time=609.728..999.063 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.55..35906356.08 rows=2424 width=380) (actual time=311.875..700.743 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.30..836916.52 rows=2424 width=6) (actual time=307.716..321.110 rows=9 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 1"
"              Workers Launched: 1"
"              ->  Parallel Index Scan using mgrs_pk on mgrs  (cost=0.29..835643.81 rows=1426 width=6) (actual time=56.503..61.134 rows=824 loops=2)"
"                    Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 15590"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.25..14467.57 rows=1 width=374) (actual time=0.721..43.588 rows=111 loops=9)"
"              ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_query_idx_l1c on products p  (cost=0.56..13146.67 rows=149 width=342) (actual time=0.178..2.674 rows=120 loops=9)"
"                    Index Cond: (mgrs_tile = mgrs.mgrs_tile)"
"                    Filter: ((sensing_time > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (cloud_cover < '100'::numeric) AND _st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'::geometry))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 67"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on l  (cost=0.69..8.86 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.338..0.338 rows=1 loops=1083)"
"                    Filter: (p.product_id = l._product_id)"
"                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.69..8.84 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.337..0.337 rows=1 loops=1083)"
"                          Group Key: locations.product_id"
"                          Filter: ('aws:sentinel-s2-l1c'::sentinel2.providers = ANY (array_agg(locations.provider)))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                          ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_locations_idx on locations  (cost=0.69..8.74 rows=3 width=110) (actual time=0.233..0.326 rows=3 loops=1083)"
"                                Index Cond: (product_id = p.product_id)"
```

We can see that the planner performs 9 loops on the products table. However, with smaller bboxes (`ST_MakeEnvelope(20, 20, 45, 45, 4326)`):

- the query does not return with current filters,
- the query returns quickly without the condition `'aws:sentinel-s2-l1c' = ANY(l.providers)`.

The `ANY` condition is true for about 90% of the products.

With bboxes even smaller (`ST_MakeEnvelope(40, 40, 45, 45, 4326)`), the query takes about 2s and the plan is:

```
"  ->  Sort  (cost=289900.87..289900.92 rows=20 width=380) (actual time=2141.380..2141.518 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: mgrs.mgrs_tile"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1361kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.53..289900.44 rows=20 width=380) (actual time=0.688..2103.530 rows=20975 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using mgrs_geom_idx on mgrs  (cost=0.28..548.63 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.563..2.740 rows=40 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry)"
"                    Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 9"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.25..14467.57 rows=1 width=374) (actual time=0.125..52.311 rows=524 loops=40)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_query_idx_l1c on products p  (cost=0.56..13146.67 rows=149 width=342) (actual time=0.042..5.000 rows=557 loops=40)"
"                          Index Cond: (mgrs_tile = mgrs.mgrs_tile)"
"                          Filter: ((sensing_time > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (cloud_cover < '100'::numeric) AND _st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 109"
"                    ->  Subquery Scan on l  (cost=0.69..8.86 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.084..0.084 rows=1 loops=22264)"
"                          Filter: (p.product_id = l._product_id)"
"                          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.69..8.84 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.083..0.083 rows=1 loops=22264)"
"                                Group Key: locations.product_id"
"                                Filter: ('aws:sentinel-s2-l1c'::sentinel2.providers = ANY (array_agg(locations.provider)))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                                ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_locations_idx on locations  (cost=0.69..8.74 rows=3 width=110) (actual time=0.032..0.078 rows=3 loops=22264)"
"                                      Index Cond: (product_id = p.product_id)"
```

With this bbox, the query  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sentinel2.mgrs WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(40, 40, 45, 45, 4326))` returns 40.
So it appears that the planner is doing the lateral query for each mgrs_tile, despite the `LIMIT` and the `ORDER BY`.

**4. Weird trick**

If I move the ORDER BY in the CTE and remove it from the main query (I know I am not supposed to do that but...) the query is lightening fast (80ms).

```sql
WITH m AS (
    SELECT mgrs_tile
    FROM sentinel2.mgrs
    WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(40, 40, 45, 45, 4326))
    --AND mgrs_tile >= '...'
    ORDER BY mgrs_tile
)
SELECT q.*
FROM m,
LATERAL (
    SELECT id, deleted, product_id, datatake_id, 
       processing_level, spacecraft, 
       sensing_time, mgrs_tile, cloud_cover, geom, l.locations
    FROM sentinel2.products p
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT product_id AS _product_id, array_agg((provider, properties)) locations, array_agg(provider) providers
        FROM sentinel2.locations
        WHERE product_id = p.product_id
        GROUP BY product_id
    ) l on p.product_id = l._product_id
    WHERE 
        mgrs_tile = m.mgrs_tile
        AND processing_level = 'l1c'
        AND _ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(40, 40, 45, 45, 4326))
        AND sensing_time > '2016-01-01'
        AND NOT deleted
        AND cloud_cover < 100
        --AND (id > ... OR mgrs_tile != '...')
        AND 'aws:sentinel-s2-l1c' = ANY(l.providers)
    ORDER BY id
) q
LIMIT 1000
```

The plan comes back with a reasonnable number of loops and the rows are still well ordered:

```
"Limit  (cost=550.31..289901.12 rows=20 width=374) (actual time=23.724..75.613 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=550.31..289901.12 rows=20 width=374) (actual time=0.653..52.276 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=549.06..549.11 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.473..0.479 rows=3 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: mgrs.mgrs_tile"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"              ->  Index Scan using mgrs_geom_idx on mgrs  (cost=0.28..548.63 rows=20 width=6) (actual time=0.095..0.395 rows=40 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (geom && '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry)"
"                    Filter: st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 9"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.25..14467.57 rows=1 width=374) (actual time=0.118..17.153 rows=333 loops=3)"
"              ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_query_idx_l1c on products p  (cost=0.56..13146.67 rows=149 width=342) (actual time=0.050..2.427 rows=358 loops=3)"
"                    Index Cond: (mgrs_tile = mgrs.mgrs_tile)"
"                    Filter: ((sensing_time > '2016-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (cloud_cover < '100'::numeric) AND _st_intersects(geom, '0103000020E610000001000000050000000000000000004440000000000000444000000000000044400000000000804640000000000080464000000000008046400000000000804640000000000000444000000000000044400000000000004440'::geometry))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 247"
"              ->  Subquery Scan on l  (cost=0.69..8.86 rows=1 width=93) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=1 loops=1074)"
"                    Filter: (p.product_id = l._product_id)"
"                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.69..8.84 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=1 loops=1074)"
"                          Group Key: locations.product_id"
"                          Filter: ('aws:sentinel-s2-l1c'::sentinel2.providers = ANY (array_agg(locations.provider)))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                          ->  Index Scan using sentinel2_locations_idx on locations  (cost=0.69..8.74 rows=3 width=110) (actual time=0.028..0.036 rows=3 loops=1074)"
"                                Index Cond: (product_id = p.product_id)"
```

---

How can I prevent the planner from executing all `LATERAL` queries in some circumstances?
Are there other ways to write the query so that it is more efficient?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Is there a point of joining to mgrs at all?  It doesn't seem to contribute anything to the result.